# Cache data driven asp web page on azure to improve speed

Tags: asp.net, azure

I am designing a data driven web site that has a page that shows a list people with associated data - contact information, hobbies etc. Each list is fairly static- it changes rarely. Presently, when a list is loaded, the data is fetched from rows containing people data from an azure table. This process is making my page loads unacceptably slow. My question is, can I pre-assemble the entire people list page html, with the associated data for each list, and save if to a blob storage? This way, if a user wants to see, say, "people list A", the pre-assembled list is received from an azure blog container and served directly to the client? I did look at azure redis, but it looks like it would be more expensive and perhaps more complicated to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You have several (almost) build-in options. With ASP.net MVC you can use [output caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which works out of the box, but it's only really usable if you want to return the same data to many people. Although you can use the [VaryByParam](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.varybyparam(v=vs.118).aspx) property to cache several different versions of the same page.

Another option, you already mentioned, is caching the data externally. You can save the list of people in Redis, or just in a [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is available since .NET Framework 4.5.

Rendering the whole page, capturing the output, saving it to blob storage, retrieve it when necessary, send it to the user and manage the caching sounds way to complicated to me for solving this common problem. I prefer the first two solutions, which are meant for scenario's like this and are used to great effect by millions of sites.